# iOS: How to display a small view on top of main view?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uiview

I'm new here, don't be very hard on me :)

Learning iOS development and trying to display a small view to enter some data to my app, which is using storyboards.

I tried adding it as subview but I can't move it from the top-left corner or make the background to fade. Any advice on how to do this?

Forgot to mention that this is for iPhone.

Thanks

Comment: What have your tried (with code examples) and what errors or result did you get?

Comment: UIViewController *controller = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"addData"];

[self presentModalViewController:controller animated:YES];

tries this, it just presents the controller in full screen. and tried as [self.view addSubview:]

Answer (score 2):

Based on your comment it seems that you don't have a clear understanding of the difference between UIView and UIViewController.

Think of a UIViewController as your screen. Your screen might be showing many different views at once, but they are all part of the UIViewController's view.

Rather then present a new UIViewController (i.e. screen), you want to do something like this:

```
//Use a XIB for this, not a storyboard
UIView *newView = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"addData" owner:self options:nil] lastObject];
[self.view addSubview:newView];
```

I suggest reading these two guides from Apple until you understand the difference between a UIView and a UIViewController:

[View Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewPG_iPhoneOS/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009503)

[View Controller Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457)

Comment: Thank you! I tried this code and it worked 

     UIView *controller = [[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"addData"] view];

Is there a way I can do a flip animation and have another set of controls on the flip side? Also, can I darken the background/make it unaccessible till the user dismisses the subview?

Comment: Those should be asked as separate questions. Actually, search around and you'll find the answers.

Comment: Is it just me or -- judging from his comment -- the original author is looking to put a new viewcontroller atop his current view?  Wouldn't the answer (as given, not in the comment) just add the view without using the view's separate controller?